# Merging in eCognition

Tags: merge, ecognition

I know how to merge two polygons in ArcGis, I have tried to merge two unclassified polygons as one in eCognition for a while now and nothing is working. still remains two separate polygons. Can someone help with a video?

Comment: The Process Tree method will merge the entire segmentation to one object.We cannot choose the polgons we want like it is in the free hand method.
Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: Yes... Filtering by condition. But I'll flag this post because isn't an answer

Answer (score 1):

You have two fast options:

**Process tree method:**

Add a child with `Basic Object Reshaping: merge region` use condition `Class-related features` / `Relations to neighbor objects` / `Existence of` / `unclassified (0)` = 1 and select parameter Candidates classes = unclassified

**Free-hand method:**

1. Add Manual Editing toolbar (right-click in superior panel).
2. Click on "Polygon selection".
3. Select a region (in your case, two polygons) .
4. Click on "Merge selected objects".
5. View results.

[image]